# Jetpack Compose - Cannot animate Scaffold's bottom bar's height

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to reveal some floating action buttons at the bottom of the screen when some other buttons, in a scrollable list, are no longer visible on the screen. Naturally, I feel like using `LazyColumn`, `AnimatedVisibility` and `Scaffold`'s bottom bar for this (I need the snackbar and the screen's content be above the floating action buttons). But the animation doesn't work as expected. As the floating buttons appear/dissapear, the bottom bar's height is not animated (but I think it could actually be that the content padding isn't animated).

The result I'm getting:

[image]

The code:

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
val isFloatingButtonVisible by derivedStateOf {
    lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex >= 2
}
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = isFloatingButtonVisible,
            enter = slideInVertically { height -> height },
            exit = slideOutVertically { height -> height }
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                repeat(2) {
                    Button(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .height(48.dp)
                            .weight(1f),
                        onClick = {}
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Something")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
) { contentPadding ->
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding),
        state = lazyListState,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
        item {
            Text(
                text = LoremIpsum(50).values.joinToString(" ")
            )
        }
        item {
            Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
                repeat(2) {
                    Button(onClick = {}) {
                        Text(text = "Bla Bla")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        item {
            Text(
                text = LoremIpsum(700).values.joinToString(" ")
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Got the right result using `AnimatedContent` instead of `AnimatedVisibility`.

[image]

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
val isFloatingButtonVisible by derivedStateOf {
    lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex >= 2
}
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        AnimatedContent(
            targetState = isFloatingButtonVisible,
            transitionSpec = {
                slideInVertically { height -> height } with
                slideOutVertically { height -> height }
            }
        ) { isVisible ->
            if (isVisible) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .border(1.dp, Color.Red)
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
                ) {
                    repeat(2) {
                        Button(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .height(48.dp)
                                .weight(1f),
                            onClick = {}
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Something")
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
            }
        }
    }
) { contentPadding ->
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding),
        state = lazyListState,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
        item {
            Text(
                text = LoremIpsum(50).values.joinToString(" ")
            )
        }
        item {
            Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
                repeat(2) {
                    Button(onClick = {}) {
                        Text(text = "Bla Bla")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        item {
            Text(
                text = LoremIpsum(700).values.joinToString(" ")
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working, but it is not clear how to control `slideOutVertically` duration. Also, only `Box` allows you to resize `LazyColumn` without unnecessary recompositions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do this with `AnimatedVisibility`. I got it like this

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

    val isFloatingButtonVisible by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex >= 1
        }
    }

    var barHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }


    var listSizeDelta by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    val bottomBarOffset = remember { Animatable(barHeight, Dp.VectorConverter) }

    LaunchedEffect(isFloatingButtonVisible) {
        if (isFloatingButtonVisible) {
            bottomBarOffset.animateTo(barHeight)
            listSizeDelta = barHeight
        } else {
            listSizeDelta = 0.dp
            bottomBarOffset.animateTo(0.dp)
        }
    }

    val density = LocalDensity.current

    BoxWithConstraints(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(width = maxWidth, height = maxHeight - listSizeDelta)
                .background(Color.Yellow),
            state = lazyListState,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
        ) {
            repeat(15) {
                item {
                    Text(
                        text = LoremIpsum(50).values.joinToString(" ")
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    translationY =
                        density.run { (-bottomBarOffset.value + barHeight).toPx() }
                }
                .background(Color.Green)
                .onSizeChanged {
                    barHeight = density.run { it.height.toDp()}
                }
                .padding(8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            repeat(2) {
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(48.dp)
                        .weight(1f),
                    onClick = {}
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Something")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think AnimatedVisibility is the problem. Did you consider using AnimatedContent? I'll try it myself maybe tomorrow. I highly doubt that there isn't something that can work for variable sizes. I don't know the size of the bottom bar ;p

Comment: @daniyelp You can use `onSizeChanged`. I have updated the answer with `onSizeChanged `. True, this requires that the height of the bar be constant

Comment: @daniyelp You need to control the height of `LazyColumn`. Otherwise, it fill all available space. You can use `onSizeChanged` to get the size instead of `BoxWithConstraints` (I haven't tried). But it will be a less efficient solution. AnimatedContent is not suitable for this task

Comment: At least one render must pass before onSizeChanged gives us the bottom bar height. For one split second, the UI isn't the one expected. Maybe it's no issue in here though. That's the first thing that crosses my mind when I see onSizeChanged being used. I wrote this before testing your code.

Comment: Also, check out my answer. I tried using AnimatedContent and it's working :p. You can try out my code. Maybe I'm blind.

Comment: @daniyelp `onSizeChanged`...You can make the initial offset outside the screen - this ensures that the bar does not appear on the screen even for 1 frame. Also you can wrap the bar with `if(isVisible)`

Answer (score -1):

The content padding in lazycolumn modifier breaks the animation;

```
LazyColumn(
   modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding) // -> Delete this.
)
```

For the same view;

```
Row(
   modifier = Modifier
      .background(Color.White) //-> Add this.
      .padding(8.dp) 
)
```

Comment: I need the contentPadding. Also, what's `background(Color.White)` for?

Comment: you will see if you try with background and not.